# opencv on ubuntu - cannot find lib files

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, opencv, g++

I am following this [guide](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_eclipse/linux_eclipse.html):

to get opencv to run on ubuntu 12.04 with eclipse juno CDT. But I get this error when I build all:

```
Building target: DisplayImage
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/usr/local/lib -o "DisplayImage"  ./src/DisplayImage.o   -lopencv_core\ opencv_imgproc\ opencv_highgui
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_core opencv_imgproc opencv_highgui
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [DisplayImage] Error 1
```

In eclipse I have added:

```
opencv_core opencv_imgproc opencv_highgui
```

in the "Libraries (-l)" box. If I run (as described in the guide):

```
pkg-config --libs opencv
```

I get:

```
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_contrib.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_gpu.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_legacy.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_nonfree.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_photo.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ts.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.so
```

so they seem to exists. But the names are a bit different compared to the guide. I have tried to change the includes in eclipse to:

```
libopencv_core.so libopencv_imgproc.so opencv_highgui
```

but that does not help. Any ideas?

EDIT:

This is how I setup the includes:

[image]

And this is how I setup the libs(linker):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you forget to set `Library search path(-L)` to `usr/local/lib/` in `C++ Linker->Libraries`:

[image]

**Update:** from your screenshot I see that all your libs are in one line. Take a look again at my screenshot.

Answer (score 4):

Ah each lib must be on a separate line in the C++linker->Libraries box.

Comment: Yes…  in my case, i remove space after each lib. And it solved the problem.